# How to disable SonataAdminBundle translations

Tags: symfony, internationalization, sonata-admin, symfony-2.3

I'm using Symfony 2.3 (LTS). I've developed a multi-locales website keeping in session the locale selected by the user ( the special parameter *_locale* )

This is the same parameter used by SonataAdminBundle to translate its labels, call-to-actions and so on. So when an admin changes the site locale for some reason, the entire backend offers all the labels translated.

I'd like to avoid this behaviour, maybe disabling, or maybe forcing SonataAdminBundle to use just one preconfigured locale.

Thank you

Eric